# sqlalchemy query object over sqlite3 returning Nones

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy 0.6.6 and sqlite 3.6.22 on Python 2.6.  When I do:

```
In [1]: for i in ses.query(UserSnapshot):
   ...:     print i
   ...:     if i is None: break
   ...:
```

I see:

```
...
<twopt.UserSnapshot object at 0x86a52f50>
<twopt.UserSnapshot object at 0x86a55050>
<twopt.UserSnapshot object at 0x86a55110>
<twopt.UserSnapshot object at 0x86a551d0>
<twopt.UserSnapshot object at 0x86a55290>
<twopt.UserSnapshot object at 0x86a55350>
None
```

My schema:

```
class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'user' 
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  blob = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
  since = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)

class UserSnapshot(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'user_snapshot'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
  blob = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
  time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

Short of dumping my entire DB, any hints as to what might cause `None` to be returned?  I searched the documentation but couldn't find any leads.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you still see this behavior in the latest version of sqlalchemy?  At this writing, 0.7.3 is the latest stable release, and many bugs are fixed between here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oy...this turned out to be due to my own fiddling with the DB outside of sqlalchemy, where I swapped out the user_snapshot table with a copy that had

```
id int primary key
```

instead of

```
id integer primary key
```

Apparently sqlite treats these differently:

```
sqlite> create table a (a integer primary key, b integer);
sqlite> insert into a (b) values (0);
sqlite> select * from a;
1|0
sqlite> create table b (a int primary key, b integer);
sqlite> insert into b (b) values (0);
sqlite> select * from b;
|0
```

The result was that many of my rows had NULL id's.

I couldn't find in http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html or http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html any mention of this peculiar distinguishing behavior.  Anyway, that's that.

Comment: sqlite has an unusual type system;  if it recognizes the data type, it will act in a way that makes sense for that type, but if it doesn't recognize the type, it just understands it to mean "any type will do";  since `int` is not the actual integer type, the autoincrementing behavior in sqlite is not activated, and so nulls are inserted as nulls instead of being converted to a new, unique key value; and when sqlalchemy session recieves a null primary key, its identity cache returns no object.  makes perfect sense